# Jinja2 ASCII to String

Tags: python, c++, jinja2, systemc

I had this line in my Jinja2 template:

```
{% for type in types %}
    top -> {{(loop.index0 + 'a')|string}}(var{{loop.index0}});
{% endfor %}
```

where types is a list of various types in C++ that is used elsewhere in the template and the output is part of a SystemC program to initialize module signals.
The goal is to get an output like this with characters starting from lowercase a:

```
top -> a(var0);
top -> b(var1);
```

However, it was giving this error: "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'" so I tried changing the template to this:

```
{% for type in types %}
    top -> {{(loop.index0 + 'a'|int)|string}}(var{{loop.index0}});
{% endfor %}
```

but then the output was this

```
top -> 0(var0);
top -> 1(var1);
```

It seems that the issue is that there is no way to convert from an integer to its corresponding ASCII character within the Jinja2 template. I tried "chr()" but that is a Python function and not a Jinja2 one and doesn't work. I was wondering if there is anyone who has had experience with this and could help me out?

Answer (score 5):

Answering the question posed by the title question: "Jinja2 ASCII to String"

```
# Returns "a" if 'my_index' is 0, "b" if 1, etc.
{{ "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[my_index] }}

# Use the char_code as the index.
{{ "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[char_code - 97] }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are a and b your types? If so you can just use their string values directly:

template.cpp

```
{% for type in types %}
top -> {{type}}(var{{loop.index0}});
{% endfor %}
```

main.py

```
import jinja2
import os.path
template_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir),
                               autoescape = False)

t = jinja_env.get_template('template.cpp')
types = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print (t.render(types=types))
```

main.py output from run:

```
top -> a(var0);

top -> b(var1);

top -> c(var2);
```

Comment: The "types" list is actually just and indicator of how many elements to have. a, b, c, etc are not the types, but are the names of variables for a module. The types list would look something like this:
types = ['uint32_t', 'char', 'float']
However, I did realize that I could just use another list which just contains all the lowercase letters so it would be
{% for type in types %}
top -> {{letters[loop.index0]}}(var{{loop.index0}});
{% endfor %}